# why can't I focus on correct uitextfield in the uitableview cell (goes over navigation bar) in iOS, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm using a `TableViewController` with custom `TableViweCell` to gather user information. inside my custom `TableViweCell` there are more than 5 `textfields`. (**NOTE : I'm using tableview controller because it helps scroll above keyboard automatically when tap on uitextfield**). so when I tap on first `uitextfield`, automatically focus on it and automatically scroll it to up(stop near the navigation bar bottom line.). then when I tap on another `uitextfield` it scrolls to up with passing the navigation bar.then user has to scroll down to type on it. what is the problem with this.

**should I use different custom uitableview cells for each textfield**

tableview .m file implementation.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HoteluserdetailformTableViewCell *formcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"hotelformcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    return formcell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return screenSize.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for this.if we want to use more than one text field we have to return that much of rows in number of rows in section method.
ex : if you want `5` text fields

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 5;
}
```

**note : use 5 text fields inside the same custom cell does not work for this.**

Comment: add view animation to scroll down on click of textfield.